# Why isn't the boost::shared_ptr -> operator declared inline?

Tags: c++, boost, inline, shared-ptr

Since `boost::shared_ptr` could be called very frequently and simply returns a pointer, isn't the `->` operator a good candidate for being `inlined`?

```
T * operator-> () const // never throws
{
    BOOST_ASSERT(px != 0);
    return px;
}
```

Would a good compiler automatically `inline` this anyway?

Should I lose any sleep over this? :-)

Comment: Nowadays, a good optimizing compiler will do a better job than you of deciding what should be inlined, so will ignore the `inline` keyword.

Comment: @Blue: Ignore the inlining part, anyway. But you're right: Compilers do inlining completely regardless to the `inline` keyword. None `inline` and `inline`'d functions alike all can be inlined.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, @GMan: you are overgeneralizing this a bit. If you cannot afford to compile with full optimization turned on (for whatever reason), you might want to control what functions are to be inlined or not. Then `inline` becomes less irrelevant. I am no expert, but I'm guessing this is one of the reasons why the keyword exists.

Comment: @Jörgen: The keyword exists for legacy reasons.  Compilers really only became that "smart" in the past 10-15 years, while C++ has been around for about 40.  The same goes for the `register` keyword.

Answer (score 18):

Functions defined (i.e. with a body) inside a class are implicitly candidates for inlining. There is no need to use the `inline` keyword in these cases, and it is unusual to do so.

Answer (score 4):

> Would a good compiler automatically inline this anyway?

Quite probably, yes, it would.

> Should I lose any sleep over this?

Better not. If you want to be super-sure (or you are super-curious), check the assembly that's going out from your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `shared_ptr` is a class **template**, so its member functions are actually **function templates**.

Since they are not `export`ed, they must not only be **declared**, but also  **defined** in all translation units where they are used, just like a function defined with the `inline` storage specifier.

In a way, `template` also means `inline`.